# Не меняется задний фон

Tags: css, html5

```css
.main-logo {
  background-color: #FF0004;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 100px;
}

.more {
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.head {
  background-color: aqua;
}

ul.menu-head li {
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
}

.logo-head {
  float: left;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-logo">
    <div class="logo"><img src="../pict/logo/logo.png"></div>
    <div class="more">
      <a>
        <h1>Узнать больше про наш продукт</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="logo-head"><img src="../pict/logo/logo.png"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="menu-head">
        <li><a>Наши продукты</a></li>
        <li><a>Советы по содержанию</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="name-page"></div>
</div>
<div class="products"></div>
<div class="foot"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пишу диплом по веб-дизайну. И тут встал вопрос. Не меняется задний фон, не понимаю почему

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Где не меняется? Всё меняется. Я вижу и красный цвет и aqua

Comment: Добавил скрин. Есть только красный цвет, а аквы нет

Comment: В инспекторе смотри. возможно картинка перекрывает весь блок....... например добавь ширину и высоту диву и увидишь  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKNR0.png

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: @rayeklok похоже верный ответ у Михаила)

Answer (score 1):

Флоаты схлопывают блок. Это можно решить, но лучше их не использовать, они не удобные, предоставляют скудный функционал. Легче использовать флексы

- `display: flex` - ставим в линию элементы внутри
- `justify-content: space-between` - выравняем во флексовом контейнере крайние элементы по краям по основной флексовой оси (основная ось это та, по которой становятся флексовые элементы)

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-logo {
  background-color: #FF0004;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.more {
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.head {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul.menu-head li {
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-logo">
    <div class="logo"><img src="../pict/logo/logo.png"></div>
    <div class="more">
      <a>
        <h1>Узнать больше про наш продукт</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="logo-head"><img src="../pict/logo/logo.png"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="menu-head">
        <li><a>Наши продукты</a></li>
        <li><a>Советы по содержанию</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="name-page"></div>
</div>
<div class="products"></div>
<div class="foot"></div>
```